Google OAuth2 connecting to googlefit account "This app is blocked" error
I have developed an app that retrieves some users' step counts from the GoogleFit API.
This application has been available to users since 2018.
And,the authentication method is logging in using OAuth2.
Most users can log in , but when some users try to log in, they get “This application is blocked” error.
Do you know what could be the cause?enter message
OAuth2 was adopted to comply with Google's security standards. Nothing has changed and an error occurs.

Please update the question to reflect the platform on which your application is running. The question could also benefit from a short excerpt of code that you use to access OAuth. This problem is likely to require the client to give permission / consent to access the application.

Dear @SmellyCat
Thank you for your comments.
Where and how do I need to get permission for this?

This problem is likely to require the client to give permission / consent to access the application.

